# How can i get real ClientRect from TGridPanel's cell when it have large BorderWidth?

Tags: delphi, graphics, draw, vcl

I'm trying to draw in each cell of a `TGridPanel` overriding the Paint event. I get the Rect for each cell through `CellRect [Row, Col]`. This works until an edge is reported. In this case, even the design in designtime is wrong: the 'ClientRect' of the cells do not correspond to the return of `CellRect`.

I tried to adjust the rect obtained from `CellRect`, but it is very complex to consider the displacement rate for each. In the image below, I have a TGripanel with a 3px border and each panel with `AlignwithMargins` = true, all `Margins` = 3px.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Native Paint:
`BorderWidth` = 3
`BorderStyle` = bsNone
(each panel is `align` = `alclient` and `AlignWithMargins` = `True`

[image: native image]

My code to get cells 'ClientRect':

```
procedure TMyCustomGridPanel.paint;
var
  Row, Col: Integer;
  rctCell: TRect;

  function GetColor(C, R: Integer): TColor;
  begin
    if odd(C + R) then
      Result:= clblack
    else
      Result:= clWhite;
  end;
begin
  inherited;

 for Row := 0 to RowCollection.Count -1 do
  begin
    for Col := 0 to ColumnCollection.Count -1 do
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := GetColor(Col, Row);
      if Canvas.Brush.Color <> clDefault then
      begin
        rctCell := CellRect[Col, Row];

        {$REGION 'Adjust first col an row'}
        if Col = 0 then
          rctCell.SetLocation(rctCell.Location.X + BorderWidth, rctCell.Location.Y);

        if Row = 0 then
          rctCell.SetLocation(rctCell.Location.X, rctCell.Location.Y + BorderWidth);
        {$ENDREGION}

        {$REGION 'ajust last cells'}
        if Col = (ColumnCollection.Count -1) then
        begin
          if Col > 0 then // tem mais de uma coluna
            rctCell.SetLocation(rctCell.Location.X - BorderWidth, rctCell.Location.Y);
          rctCell.Right := ClientRect.Right;
        end;

        if Row = (RowCollection.Count -1) then
        begin
          if Row > 0 then
            rctCell.SetLocation(rctCell.Location.X, rctCell.Location.Y - BorderWidth);
          rctCell.Bottom := ClientRect.Bottom;
        end;

        {$ENDREGION}
        Canvas.Pen.Style := psClear;
        Canvas.FillRect(rctCell);
      end;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Result with my code:
(the panels are just to show that CellRect is not the 'ClientRect' to put a control)

```
GridPanel
BorderWidth = 10
BorderStyle = bsNone
Color = clmarron

Panels
Align = alClient
Color = clgray
AlignWithMargins = true
```

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you're really trying to do. If you want to paint something in the panels, you should override `Paint()` in the panels, not in `TGridPanel`.

Comment: "I'm trying to draw in each cell of a TGridPanel overriding the Paint event." Is not clear?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I adjusted the sample code to reproduce my scenario, without other dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design time rendering of the cell borders (the dotted lines) of a `TGridPanel` does not take into account the borders of the panel. Thus they do not visually coincide with components you have placed in the grid cells. This is most apparent e.g. with panels of which the `Align` property is set to `alClient`.

To know the actual rectangle of a cell, in coordinates of the `TGridPanel`, you can use `OffsetRect` to adjust for the border widths.

```
var
  row, col: integer;
  r: TRect;
begin
  ...
  r := CellRect[Col, Row];
  OffsetRect(r, BorderWidth, BorderWidth);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Its solution is elegant and simple. I am still having a issue with  the space occupied by the internal panels that are own painted with 1 pixel less inside the border, even with the panel ``BorderWidth`` = 0.

Comment: @AnselmoMS Thanks to you too. I'm not sure I get your comment. Why do you think the panels are missing pixels? Are the pixels missing both vertically and horizontally? Perhaps this should be posted as a new question, especially if the problem occurs also outside of a `GridPanel`.